# multiple instances of external svg

Tags: svg

I'm trying to use external svg file to link particular element from svg stack to "background-image"/"content" of the button element using #fragment identifier.
i.e.:

```
Button1 - background-image: url(icons.svg#fragment1);
Button2 - background-image: url(icons.svg#fragment2);
```

External icons.svg consists tons of fragments and pretty big.
Everything works perfectly in all browsers. However for each button that needs only one particular fragment it loads whole svg. At the end, having (let's say)  10 buttons, I've got 10 loaded instances of the whole svg.
An ideal solution (IMHO) would be to use the tag "use" with "inlined" SVG but as far as I know such combination wont work.
Using URI encoded fragments not a solution for my particular case.
What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using a background image if you use the svg as a child of your button element.

To use different icons for different states, you can add multiple icons and only make them visible depending on the state of the button.

```css
button:hover use.hover,
button:active use.active {
    display: inline;
}
button use:not(.default),
button:hover use.default,
button:active use.default,
button:active use.hover {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- inline your icons -->
<svg display="none">
  <symbol id="icon1" viewBox="0 0 30 20">
    <ellipse cx="15" cy="10" rx="15" ry="10" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="icon2" viewBox="0 0 30 20">
    <rect x="5" y="5" width="20" height="10" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="icon3" viewBox="0 0 30 20">
    <path d="M7,17H23L15,3z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<button style="width:80px;height:30px;">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <use class="default" href="#icon1" />
    <use class="hover" href="#icon2" />
    <use class="active" href="#icon3" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: With such approach(add svg as child) another problem appears: - I need alternate already existing structure (add child using javascript, - I need "hover" & "active" buttons state? - I need position more than one fragment aligned on top of each other for each button (let's say "ellipse" on top of "rectangle"). With CSS I can do it by assigning to "background-mage"- "#square" and to "content"-"#ellipse" with ":before" for each state

Comment: Add multiple `<use>` elements and set them visible according to state, i. e. `button use { display: none } button:active use.active { display: inline }`

Comment: My great appreciation if you can show exact codes using your sample with any additional symbol.

Comment: button:active seems to append something like inner-padding (approx 1px shift from the top left) in IE11. In all other browsers works fine. position:relative, padding:0 won't help. What could be done?

Comment: Each browser applies his own styling to buttons - it's a general chalenge to web designers. Here is a nice article discussing some of the issues: [Overriding Default Button Styles](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-default-button-styles/)

Comment: Article didn't help. However problem solved by adding:button:active > svg{
position:relative;}. Have no idea why it works, but it works.